# Use contents of file as two separate variables

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, rename

I need to do two things...

1. Rename all text files within a directory. Each file is named with a word and a number with a space between them. I want to remove the number from the file name.

   For example....

   ```
    House 21.txt -> House.txt
   ```
2. Each of the above files have the same content as their name. They each have one word and one number with a space between them. I need to be able to take the word and the number and save them as separate variables.

   For example:

   ```
    Car 2     -> Set var1=Car & var2=2
   ```

I just do not know the correct way to strip the appropriate info from the files when the content does not have the same amount of characters. If all I had to do was remove the last 5 characters I could do something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.TXT) do (
   set oldName=%%a
   set newName=!oldName:~0,-5!
   echo !newName!>!newName!.txt
)
```

But each file is a different length and only removing 5 characters would not work for those that need 6 or more. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.txt) do call:treat "%%~na"
exit/b

:treat
set count=1
for %%b in (%~1) do (
       set $var!count!=%%b
      set /a count+=1)

echo !$var1! - !$var2!
echo ren "%~1%.txt" !$var1!.txt

pause
```

This will create in every iteration `$var1` and `$var2` you can then rename `%1` as  `!$var1!`.

Just remove the echo if the output is correct for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! that seems to do it for the first .txt in the folder.  How do I get it to itterate through all .txt files in the folder?  Can I add an indexer?

Comment: This will do it for every `.txt`file. Just remove the pause.

Comment: Im sorry if I am missing something but even when removing the pause it just continues with the rest of my code.  Only editing the first .txt file.  I must be missing something, I willkeep looking.

Comment: replace the `pause` with `goto :eof` to tell it, that the `call` is finished and that it has to "go back". If you have more code to be executed after, replace the `exit /b` with `goto continue` and add a label `:continue` after the (new) `goto :eof`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 unrelated questions.

**Part 1 - Rename the files**

If all .txt files within the directory that match "* *.txt" are to be renamed, then you can do the following:

```
:: Preserve any existing files that have no extension
ren *. *.preserve
:: Strip off everything from the space onward
ren "* *.txt" "* "
:: Restore the .txt extension
ren *. *.txt
:: Restore the files with no extension
ren *.preserve *.
```

This solution has 4 steps, but it operates in bulk, so it can rename a great many files very quickly.

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for help on why the above works

The above will also rename files like "word1 word2 45.txt", or "word1 word2.txt". You could use the following script to be more specific.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d "* *.txt"^|findstr /ric:"^[^ ][^ ]* [0-9][0-9]*\.txt$"
) do for /f %%A in ("%%F") do ren "%%F" "%%A.txt"
```

This 2nd solution is very precice, but it must iterate each file, so it will be slower if there are a great number of files.

**Part 2 - Capture the content of each line in two variables**

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%A in ("house 21.txt") do (
  echo the word = %%A
  echo the number = %%B
)
```

Once you have the line parsed into FOR variables `%%A` and `%%B`, you can do what you want with them. You could set an environment variable..., whatever.